# How to fix «event coreslct» error?

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I have an AppleScript source with this code:

```
tell "Microsoft Word" 
    «event coreslct» (last row of table X of document Y)
    insert rows selection position below number of rows Z
end tell
```

After some research, I found that `coreslct` is the code for the select command. It's used in all AppleScriptable Office applications, and has been around in both Office 2008 and 2011.

However, the code seem to have [disappeared from Office 2016](https://github.com/doekman/sdef)...

How can I fix this? Our users use both Office 2011 and 2016...